# First to use React-Native got Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Hi，I got an  Unexpected token error when I‘m first use React-Native: bundling failed: "SyntaxError /Users/Lyle/SwcRN/SWCRN/App.js: Unexpected token (17:15)"

Here's my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    return <Text>Hello, Navigation!</Text>;
  }
}

export default const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('RNSWC', () => SimpleApp);
```

And Line 17 is

```
 export default const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
```

And my package.json

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-clone-referenced-element": "^1.0.1",
        "react-native": "0.48.3",
        "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
        "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "^21.0.2",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
        "jest": "^21.1.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0-alpha.12"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "verbose": true,
        "setupFiles": [
            "./jest/setup.js"
        ],
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation)"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "^image![a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+$": "GlobalImageStub",
            "^[@./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\\.(png|gif)$": "RelativeImageStub"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope some helps,Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should modify the line 17 of your code like this to solve the issue:

```
const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});
```

Comment: Thankssssss a lot!

Comment: Happy to help you.